# Android - Limit app to handsets only not working for Google Pixel

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using the code below in my AndroidManifest.xml to limit the app to only handsets on Google Play.  This works great, but for some reason the app does NOT show up when using a Google Pixel phone.

I'm guessing the resolution is much higher or something and I need to add a definition for it.  From what I see, the Google Pixel phone has 1080x1920 resolution.  If I add that to my definitions here, will that take care of it or is there something additional I need to do?

```
<!-- Only permit app to be used on handsets, prevent tablets -->
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="small" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <!-- LG G3 QHD Resolution -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <!--- Nexus 6P -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="560" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="560" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="560" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="560" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: "This works great" -- not really. For example, `xlarge` would not seem to qualify as a "handset", unless perhaps your name is Hagrid. :-) With respect to your problem, it is probably a missing density.

Comment: @CommonsWare - lol, understood.  It looks like the Google Pixel is a density of 441 and the Google Pixel XL is a density of 534.  Wouldn't the definition I have in place for the Nexus 6P handle this?

Comment: I would assume that you need `420` for the Pixel. `560` should cover the Pixel XL. Basically, every Android release, you need to head back to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) and update your `<compatible-screens>` to whitelist every density, including any newly-added ones.

Comment: @CommonsWare - so it looks like I could simply add an entry for xxhdpi and xxxhdpi in each screen size.  Or would you suggest I add 420 and 560 specifically.

Comment: `xxhdpi` is 480 and `xxxhdpi` is 640. 420 is closer to the Pixel than any of those, and there is no symbolic name for that density. You already have `560`.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thank you I will add a new definition for 480.

Comment: @CommonsWare - just to finish out this question, if you are able to add your comments as a answer I will accept as correct.  Adding the additional definitions for compatible-screens seems to have done the trick

Comment: Since you know what you did, I suggest that you answer your own question with the steps that you followed that worked.